# How to pretty-print tree-like value step by step?

Tags: sml, smlnj

So I've got a datatype:

```
datatype ex = A of int | B of ex * ex;
```

and an example variable:

```
val x = (B (A 1, B (A 2, A 3)));
```

I want to be printing through it like this:

```
"(1, (2, 3))"
```

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: Think recursively and pattern-matchingly.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming this pretty-printer is going to be a `pp` *: ex → string*, here is a template:

```
fun pp (A i) = ...
  | pp (B (ex1, ex2)) = ...
```

This template pattern matches against every possible value constructor for the type *ex*. The patterns go one level deep, so for your example value, `ex1` is bound to `A 2`, and `ex2` is bound to `A 3` in the first iteration of the call. You want to handle `ex1` and `ex2` recursively in the same way as you handled `ex0` being `B (A 1, B (A 2, A 3))`.

For concatenating strings, you might consider `op ^` *: string × string → string* or `String.concat` *: string list → string*:

```
- val test1 = "hello" ^ "world";
> val test1 = "helloworld" : string
- val test2 = String.concat [ "if ", "you've ", "got ", "many ", "strings!" ];
> val test2 = "if you've got many strings!" : string
```

For pretty-printing integers, you may consider `Int.toString` *: int → string*. You may want to wrap this function, since Standard ML presents negative integers a little funky:

```
- val test3 = Int.toString ~5;
> val test3 = "~5" : string
```